# Joomla 3.2.4 jdatabase unknown column in where clause

Tags: mysql, joomla3.0

I am using Hikashop cart in joomla. Whenever a user adds a product to their cart, Hikashop adds the user's session id to the #__hikashop_cart table. I am trying to select that session id by matching it to the id value obtained from the JFactory::getSession code.

ATM I get the following error:

1054 - Unknown column 'acl7e1bn099rrlhkvsrhl13bu7' in 'where clause' SQL=SELECT `session_id` FROM `hady9_hikashop_cart` WHERE session_id = acl7e1bn099rrlhkvsrhl13bu7

My query is below, any help would be appreciated.

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$id = $user->get('id');

$session =& JFactory::getSession();
$thesession = $session->getId();

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query
 ->select($db->quoteName('session_id'))
 ->from($db->quoteName('#__hikashop_cart'))
 ->where('session_id = '.$thesession);

$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadResult();
echo $results;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT session_id
FROM hady9_hikashop_cart
WHERE session_id = acl7e1bn099rrlhkvsrhl13bu7
```

You've listed `acl7e1bn099rrlhkvsrhl13bu7` without quotes, so MySQL treats it as a column name, which of course does not exist. Quoting it should solve the problem:

```
$query
 ->select($db->quoteName('session_id'))
 ->from($db->quoteName('#__hikashop_cart'))
 ->where('session_id = '. $db->quote($thesession));
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got to quote your session id, best with the `quote()` method.

```
$query
 ->select($db->quoteName('session_id'))
 ->from($db->quoteName('#__hikashop_cart'))
 ->where('session_id = '. $db->quote($thesession));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT session_id FROM hady9_hikashop_cart 
          WHERE session_id = acl7e1bn099rrlhkvsrhl13bu7
```

Here the resulting query should be

```
SELECT session_id FROM hady9_hikashop_cart 
       WHERE session_id = 'acl7e1bn099rrlhkvsrhl13bu7'
```

Make necessary changes to add quots around acl7e1bn099rrlhkvsrhl13bu7.